# Run subprocess and nothing output to logging

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, stdout

Suppose that I have two Python scripts:

The first script named `test.py` which outputs a "Test" with `logging`

```py
import logging

logging.info("Test")
```

The second script calls the first script with `subprocess` and redirects IO.

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['python',  'test.py'], 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(p.stdout.read())
```

The second script outputs nothing instead of "Test".
If I replace `print("Test")` with `logging.info("Test")`, everything works fine.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to note here:

1. **Logging level is set to WARNING by default**
2. **The log is written to stderr, rather than stdout**

A simple test can demonstrate this,

```
$ python3 -c 'import logging; logging.info("hello world")'
$
$ python3 -c 'import logging; logging.warning("hello world")' >/dev/null
WARNING:root:hello world
```

Also,

```
>>> import sys
>>> 
>>> code = """import logging
... logging.warning("hello world")
... """
>>> 
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-c', code], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
WARNING:root:hello world
CompletedProcess(args=['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', 'import logging\nlogging.warning("hello world")\n'], returncode=0, stdout=b'') # see stdout is empty ?
>>> subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-c', code], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
CompletedProcess(args=['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', 'import logging\nlogging.warning("hello world")\n'], returncode=0, stderr=b'WARNING:root:hello world\n') # see stderr have the data
```

**Note:**
You should probably set your logging conf properly :)

Comment: Another solution: adding `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)` to test.py also works.

Comment: Sure. I was just pointing out that, the code given didn't have any logging set. So that's why no data were coming out :). But yeah, you should set your logging conf properly to your needs